# Is there a way to ensure a specific thread has at one point acquired a semaphore?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, semaphore

I have created a bank simulation using threads and semaphores - and my goal is for the three bank employee threads to serve all of the customers (there will be a set amount of 50). To do this - I have created a semaphore called canLeave and what I am attempting to do is say - a thread acquires the canLeave semaphore so long as they have been served - otherwise they have to continue waiting to be served by a bank employee. My issue is, once three customers have been served (there are only three bank workers) - the code ended despite there being unserved customers. To solve this I added an integer hasBeenServed, and every time a thread acquired canLeave, I increased the count of has been served and put my run method in a while loop thats says while hasBeenServed < totalCustomers continue to run but this leads to an never ending loop.

```
static public class Customer extends Thread{
        int id;
        boolean action; // if true, deposit - if false, withdraw
        Customer(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                do {
                    //boolean notDone = true;
                    int teller = -1;
                    //action = new Random().nextBoolean();
                    enter.acquire();
                    System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " entered the bank");
                    availableTellers.acquire();
                    if (availabletellersBruh[0] == -1) {
                        availabletellersBruh[0] = id;
                        action = new Random().nextBoolean();
                        teller = 0;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " chooses Teller " + Integer.toString(0));
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " introduces itself to Teller " + Integer.toString(0));
                        customerCommunication[0] = id;
                        //totalCustomers[id] = 1;
                        if (action) {
                            convoNumber = 1;
                        } else {
                            convoNumber = 2;
                        }
                        conversation.release();
                        canLeave.acquire();
                        hasBeenServed++;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " leaves the building");
                    } else if (availabletellersBruh[1] == -1) {
                        availabletellersBruh[1] = id;
                        action = new Random().nextBoolean();
                        teller = 1;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " chooses Teller " + Integer.toString(1));
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " introduces itself to Teller " + Integer.toString(1));
                        //totalCustomers[id] = 1;
                        customerCommunication[1] = id;
                        if (action) {
                            convoNumber = 1;
                        } else {
                            convoNumber = 2;
                        }
                        conversation.release();
                        canLeave.acquire();
                        hasBeenServed++;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " leaves the building");
                    } else if (availabletellersBruh[2] == -1) {
                        availabletellersBruh[2] = id;
                        action = new Random().nextBoolean();
                        teller = 2;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " chooses Teller " + Integer.toString(2));
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " introduces itself to Teller " + Integer.toString(2));
                        //totalCustomers[id] = 1;
                        customerCommunication[2] = id;
                        if (action) {
                            convoNumber = 1;
                        } else {
                            convoNumber = 2;
                        }
                        conversation.release();
                        canLeave.acquire();
                        hasBeenServed++;
                        System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " leaves the building");
                    }

                    //canLeave.acquire();
                    availableTellers.release();
                    //System.out.println("Customer " + Integer.toString(id) + " leaves the building");
                    enter.release();
                }while(hasBeenServed < MAX_CUSTOMERS);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error in Thread " + id + ": " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also at one point tried to create an array full of the different customers ids, and if they had been served their id would be changed to a -1 , and we should continue to serve so long as there exists a number in the array > -1, but this resulted in the same infinite loop problem.

```
static public class Teller extends Thread{
        int id;
        //boolean action;
        Teller(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                //boolean finished = false;
                    availableTellers.release();
                    System.out.println("Teller " + id + " is ready!");
                    enter.release();
                    //action = new Random().nextBoolean();
//                conversation.acquire();
//                if(action){
//                    System.out.println("the customer wanted to withdraw");
//                }else if(!action){
//                    System.out.println("the customer wanted to deposit");
//                }

                    conversation.acquire();
                    if (convoNumber == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Customer " + customerCommunication[id] + " wants to withdraw");
                        bankAction = 1;
                        tellerToBank.release();
                        Safe(bankAction, id);
                    } else if (convoNumber == 2) {
                        System.out.println("Customer " + customerCommunication[id] + " wants to deposit");
                        bankAction = 2;
                        tellerToBank.release();
                        Safe(bankAction, id);
                    }

                    conversation.release();
                    canLeave.release();
                    enter.acquire();
                    availableTellers.acquire();

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error in Thread " + id + ": " + e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Anything helps, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a semaphore you could just create an fixed thread pool of size 3 to simulate 3 bank employees and submit 50 tasks to it to simulate 50 customers

```
class Customer implements Runnable
{
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
   //serve Customer using global synchronized bank variables 
 }
}

ExecutorService bankEmployees=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
 bankEmployees.execute(new Customer());
```

While the 3 threads are executing ll other customer's will have to wait in the thread pools internal queue so no customer's are lost